# Windows 10 OOBE Post-Setup: How to allow PowerShell Add-AppxPackage?

Tags: windows, installation, appx, msix, post-install

regarding a missing AppxPackage error on the last official Win 10 LTSC-Release I want to automatically install it in the post setup of Windows setup processing: Out of Box Experience (OOBE), the first boot UI. Therefore, I have the .appx file and put the following line in the SetupComplete.cmd:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command "Add-AppxPackage %WINDIR%\Setup\Files\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.30704.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.appx" >> %WINDIR%\Setup\Files\log.txt
```

I am able to execute this line manually in a non-elevated PowerShell console but unfortunately, this is not working automatically within the Windows Setup processing as it says in the log (sorry, it is German):

> Add-AppxPackage : Fehler bei Bereitstellung. HRESULT: 0x80073CF9,
> Fehler bei der Installation. Wenden Sie sich an den
> Softwarehersteller. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80073CF9) Der
> Bereitstellungsvorgang Add fr das Paket
> "Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.30704.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe" von der
> Installationsanforderung
> "Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.30704.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.appx" wurde
> abgelehnt, da dieser  Vorgang mit dem lokalen Systemkonto nicht
> ausgefhrt werden darf. HINWEIS: Wenn Sie weitere Informationen
> wnschen, suchen Sie im Ereignisprotokoll nach [ActivityId]
> 895ecdc3-eb9b-0002-0fcf-5e899bebd701, oder verwenden Sie die
> Befehlszeile Get-AppxLog -ActivityID
> 895ecdc3-eb9b-0002-0fcf-5e899bebd701 In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
>
> - Add-AppxPackage C:\Windows\Setup\Files\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.3 ...
>
> ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Windows\Setu...kyb3d8bbwe.appx:String) [Add-AppxPackage],
> IOException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
> ```

Why is the local system account not able to install that package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSIX/AppX application packages are installed separately for each Windows user account - the app files are extracted to a central system location, but the registration of the app with the system has to be done for each user. I don't know why the Local System account is specifically banned from installing packages, but I can guess why that is so: it doesn't make sense for app packages to be installed for a user account that doesn't even represent a real person, let alone one that can login to the device.

If you'd like the package you're trying to install to be available to all users on the computer, you should *"provision"* the package using the Deployment Imaging and Servicing Manager (DISM). Provisioned packages will be installed automatically for all existing user accounts the next time they login, and for all newly created accounts on first login.

With [DISM's `/Add-ProvisionedAppXPackage` subcommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-app-package--appx-or-appxbundle--servicing-command-line-options?view=windows-11#add-provisionedappxpackage) ([PowerShell version: `Add-AppXProvisionedPackage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/dism/Add-AppxProvisionedPackage?view=windowsserver2019-ps)), you can add a provisioned package to the running copy of Windows. I recommend you not do this in OOBE but earlier, in sysprep audit mode:

```
:: .bat or .cmd batch file would look like this:
Dism.exe -online -add-provisionedAppxPackage -packagePath:X:\whatever.appx

# PowerShell .ps1 script would look like this:
Add-AppXProvisionedPackage -Online -PackagePath X:\whatever.appx
```

You could also use DISM to provision the package in a Windows installation image (.WIM file) before Windows even gets installed on the device:

```
:: use Dism.exe -get-wiminfo to find the WIM's "index" number for the Windows edition or custom image you want to change
Dism.exe -mount-wim -wimFile:D:\sources\install.wim -index:1 -mountDir:X:\WimMount
Dism.exe -image:X:\WimMount -add-provisionedAppxPackage -packagePath:X:\whatever.appx
Dism.exe -unmount-wim -mountDir:X:\WimMount -commit

# use Get-WindowsImage to find the index for the image you want to change
Mount-WindowsImage -ImagePath D:\sources\install.wim -Index 1 -Path X:\WimMount
Add-AppXProvisionedPackage -Path X:\WimMount -PackagePath X:\whatever.appx
Dismount-WindowsImage -Path X:\WimMount -Save
```

Comment: So, as there are no pre-defined or existing users before it processes the AutoUnattend.xml it is not possible to include that package in a general Windows 10 LTSC .iso file?

Comment: It is possible if you do offline image servicing of the installation image file (X:\sources\install.wim on the disc/ISO). I'll edit my answer to add that as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the DISM commands on the install.wim worked like a charme. The only thing I needed to add was `-SkipLicense` at the end of the `Dism.exe -image ...` command.